# php mail adds random spaces and floating elements

Tags: html, css, php

I have some strange thing with php mail() function.
When I send a mail with php it randomly adds spaces and some of the float elements are not working.

These are my headers:

```
$headers     = 'From: ' . $website_naam . ' <' . $eigen_emailadres . '>' . PHP_EOL;
$headers    .= 'Reply-To: ' . $naam_verzender . ' <' . $email_verzender . '>' . PHP_EOL;
$headers    .= ($bcc_emailadres != '') ? 'Bcc: ' . $bcc_emailadres . PHP_EOL : '';
$headers    .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
$headers    .= 'X-Priority: Normal' . PHP_EOL;
$headers    .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
$headers    .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . PHP_EOL;
```

And this is my message:

```
$message  = '<html><body style="font-family:Open Sans; margin:0; padding:0; font-size:14px; color:#4a4a4a;">';
$message .= '<head>';
$message .= '<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">';
$message .= '</head>';
$message .= '<div style="width:930px; margin-top:30px; background-color:#fff;">';
$message .= '<div id="logo" style="width:395px; height:54px; float:left;"><a href="http://www.klumpers.nl"><img src="http://www.klumpers.nl/images/logo.png" alt="Klumpers Goud en Diamanthandel" /></a></div>';
$message .= '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
$message .= '<div style="height:1px; width:930px; background-color:#e2e2e2; margin-top:15px;"></div>';
$message .= '<div style="width:410px; background-color:#f7f7f7; margin-top:20px; padding:20px; float:left;">';
$message .= '<p style="font-size:20px; font-weight:400; color:#4a4a4a; margin:0 0 15px 0;">Gouden sieraden en voorwerpen</p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;8 karaat 33,3% goud <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.333,2)).' per gram</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">14 karaat 58,5% goud <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.585,2)).' per gram</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">18 karaat 75,0% goud <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.750,2)).' per gram</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">20 karaat 83,3% goud <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.833,2)).' per gram</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">21 karaat 87,5% goud <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.875,2)).' per gram</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">22 karaat 91,6% goud <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.916,2)).' per gram</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">24 karaat 99,9% goud <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.999,2)).' per gram</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="font-size:20px; font-weight:400; color:#4a4a4a; margin:15px 0 15px 0;">Zilveren sieraden en voorwerpen</p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">2e gehalte zilver 83,5% <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_zilver * 0.80 * 0.835,2)).' per kilo</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">1e gehalte zilver 92,5% <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_zilver * 0.80 * 0.925,2)).' per kilo</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">Zilveren gulden 72,0% <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_zilver_gram * 0.80 * 0.720 * 6.475 / 1000,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">Zilveren rijksdaalder 72,0% <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_zilver_gram * 0.80 * 0.720 * 15 / 1000,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">Zilveren tientje 72,0% <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_zilver_gram * 0.80 * 0.720 * 25 / 1000,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="font-size:20px; font-weight:400; color:#4a4a4a; margin:15px 0 15px 0;">Officieel gestempelde edelmetaal baren</p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">Baren fijn goud 99,99% <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers["goud_koers"],2)).' per kilo</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">Baren fijn zilver 99,9% <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers["zilver_koers"],2)).'  per kilo</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">Baren fijn platina 99,5% <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers["platina_koers"],2)).' per kilo</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">Baren fijn palladium 99,5% <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers["palladium_koers"],2)).' per kilo</span></p>';
$message .= '</div>';// einde linker box
$message .= '<div style="width:410px; background-color:#f7f7f7; margin-top:20px; padding:20px; float:right;">';
$message .= '<p style="font-size:20px; font-weight:400; color:#4a4a4a; margin:0 0 15px 0;">Gouden Munten</p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">Muntgoud 90,00% <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.900,2)).' per gram</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">Dukaat 3,49 gram <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.983 * 3.49,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">20 Frank Belgie 6,45 gram <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.900 * 6.45,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">20 Frank Frankrijk 6,45 gram <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.900 * 6.45,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">20 Frank Zwitserland 6,45 gram <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.900 * 6.45,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">20 Lire Italie 6,45 gram <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.900 * 6.45,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">10 Gulden Nederland 6,72 gram <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers["goud_koers"] / 1000 * 0.92 * 0.900 * 6.72,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">20 Mark Duitsland 7,96 gram <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.900 * 7.96,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">Souvereign Engeland 7,99 gram <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.916 * 7.99,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">20 Kroner D-marken 8,96 gram <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.900 * 8.96,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">100$ Canada 16,96 gram <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.916 * 16.96,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">50 ECU Belgie 17,28 gram <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.900 * 16.96,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">Maple Leaf Canada 31,10 gram <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers["goud_koers"] / 1000 * 0.96 * 0.999 * 31.1035,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">100$ Australie 31,10 gram <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers["goud_koers"] / 1000 * 0.96 * 0.999 * 31.1035,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">20$ USA 33,43 gram <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.900 * 33.43,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">100 Corona Oosterijk 33,87 gram <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.900 * 33.87,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">Krugerrand Zuid Afrika 33,93 gram <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers["goud_koers"] / 1000 * 0.92 * 0.916 * 33.93,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">50$ USA 33,93 gram <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.916 * 33.93,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '<p style="line-height:12px;">50 Pesos Mexico 41,67 gram <span style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">&#8364; '.sprintf("%01.2f",round($koers_goud * 0.900 * 41.67,2)).' per stuk</span></p>';
$message .= '</div>'; // einde rechter box
$message .= '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
$message .= '</div>';// einde container
$message .= '</body></html>';
```

And this outputs in G-mail client this:

[image]

Other E-mail clients are even worse.

Comment: Do you check if names and email addresses you input in the headers are valid ones? If not, you're open to mail header injection. And those HTML entities should be written without spaces, e.g. `&#8364;`. Why not just send mail in UTF-8 and deliver a plain `€`?

Comment: css floats among other css properties don't work in the majority of email clients unfortunately, so I doubt PHP's mail() function has anything to do with that

Comment: see http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ for more information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the `mail` function that messes things up. It's the mail client. Don't rely on floating elements in e-mails. The HTML and CSS support of email clients is not in par with browsers.

You should use tables instead. At least they are reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bart that CSS is an issue in mail clients. But I where having the same issue and was only using lists simple HTML, see below:

```
<ol>
<li>{$orderID} is ouder dan 2 maand en niets betaald is geannuleerd!</li>
</ol>
```

This resulted in:

```
45645645 is ouder dan 2 maand en niets betaald is geannuleerd!
68867676 is ouder dan 2 maand en niets betaald is geannuleerd!
45678545 is ouder dan 2 maan d en niets betaald is geannuleerd!
45667845 is ouder dan 2 maand en niets betaald is geannuleerd!
97856745 is ouder dan 2 maand en niets betaald is geannuleerd!
```

The 3th line show a space that shouldn't be there. Sometimes there was even HTML `< li>` in the mail, but also a space added inside the HTML tag. The same happend when everything changed to tables.

For me, the solution was adding a `\n` in the HTML. So the code above changed to:

```
<ol>\n
<li>{$orderID} is ouder dan 2 maand en niets betaald is geannuleerd!</li>\n
</ol>\n
```

Now the spaces are gone in the mail. So there's more than only CSS. No idea why `\n` solves the issue, but it works!